# Connect a G4 Mac to the internet connection on an iMac running OS X v10.10.5

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, internet-connection, osx-yosemite, connection-sharing

What do I have to do to connect a G4 Mac running a much older operating system, to an iMac using OS X v10.10.5? The iMac is connected to the internet through a Comcast modem/router with an Ethernet cable.  I want to use a wireless connection from the G4 to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you connect the G4 Mac directly to a spare Ethernet LAN port on the Comcast router?

Well, since you specifically said you want to connect it via the iMac running OS X v10.10.5:

On the iMac, go into `System Preferences > Sharing` and check the checkbox to enable `Internet Sharing`.

```
Share your connection from: [Ethernet]
To computers using: [√] Wi-Fi
```

Then hit the `(Wi-Fi Options…)` button and set a network name, channel, security mode, and password.

You'll definitely have to select a 2.4GHz channel (1-13), since the built-in Wi-Fi cards in PowerPC Macs never supported the 5GHz band.

Depending on how old your G4 Mac is, and how old a version of Mac OS you have on it, you may have to opt for no wireless security. Some early G4 Macs were from the days before even WPA[1] existed, but OS X v10.10.5 doesn't let you opt for old, broken WEP, and it doesn't let you opt for WPA, because vanishingly few devices ever supported WPA without supporting WPA2. So you either have to select modern trustworthy security or no security at all.

Answer (score -1):

There is a detailed procedure found at this site hosted by the University of Oregon:

https://it.uoregon.edu/connect-macs

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon.  This answer is less then helpful.  Include the relevant information in the answer itself.